# Android, The virtual keyboard hides the EditText

Tags: android, keyboard

The virtual keyboard hides the EditText so you cant see what are you typing. What can I do for this?

Comment: This is not the way to ask the question. Give some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an `android:softInputMode` attribute for your Activity element in your Manifest.

See the [Manifest  documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) for a full list of valid values and their effect. The ones of particular interest to you will likely be `adjustPan` and `adjustResize`.

Answer (score 0):

Put your layout in a `ScrollView`. This way the keyboard will push the content up when you focus the `EditText`.